# How to enumerate and delete windows events?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

Windows events logs are usually stored in `%SystemRoot%\System32\winevt\Logs`. All files are some kind of databases, I want to ask how programmatically data could be enumed from `*.evt` and `*.evtx` files into separate records and how those records could be removed from the system.

I have found [Windows Event Log Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385784%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), however I'm looking for solution which works on XP. Latter on tried [Event Logging Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363654%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Using this API I managed to read data as single records, however there is only one function for deletion, it is [ClearEventLog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363637%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). However this deletes all events from logs. I'm looking for solution where I could be able to delete single record.

**Important note:** I'm programming with C++ so C# and .net solutions aren't helpful, also I need to have compatibility with Windows-XP.

Answer (score 2):

API to read from event logs exists.

- [`OpenEventLog` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/aa363672%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) - Opens a handle to the specified event log
- `ReadEventLog` function - Reads the specified number of entries from the specified event log. The function can be used to read log entries in chronological or reverse chronological order.
- [Querying for Event Information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb427356%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) shows how to open an event log, read events from the log, print information about the events, and then close the event log.
- [Event Logging Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363654%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) - the API itself

Comment: Thanks, also [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363654%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) can be found full list of API procedures.

Comment: Also, a fun thing you can do is a backup of event log into external file. Such `.EVT` file can be transferred for offsite/offline review.

Comment: Hey one more question about this, you gave a link to some API. Now I have fully working scan mechanism, however this API has function `ClearEventLog`, this deletes all data in some event log, do you know something to delete single record?

Comment: I don't think it's supposed to work with individual entry deletion. The log is updated incrementally, and you don't have flexibility to delete an entry.